# list all branches with names that contain foo

Tags: regex, git

I've cloned a repo with a lot of branches. I'm looking for a specific branch with a name that contains "foo". What commands should I use to narrow down the list quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git branch --list <pattern>
```

NOTE: when specifying pattern the --list option is required or a new branch will be created

Answer (score 1):

using a linux terminal you can use this command:

```
git branch -a | grep foo
```